# Unspecified Error - Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have downloaded the program 2 days ago, it was working...
Today it's showing the error box:

"Unspecified error(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005(E_FAIL))"

Which doesn't let me to open any of my web-applications, does anyone knows how to fix that problem?
---Thanks

Comment: I have re-installed the program but still got the same error

Answer (score -1):

Try repairing your Microsoft Visual Studio in your control panel - > add/delete software. Click MVS and select repair.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, I have re-installed the program but got the same error